# Live stream with libstreaming and 3G/LTE

Tags: android, google-glass, vlc, rtsp, libstreaming

I am using libstreaming (https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) for doing streaming for my android phone to VLC.

In a local network, I get to watch the streaming in VLC OK, but when i disable wifi and i Use 3g/lte, I don't get to watch the streaming in VLC.

So...how can i do streaming with 3g/lte?

PD: I am using example 1 of this https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples

Thanks!

Comment: How do you open url in VLC?

Comment: Maybe NAT is your enemy.

Comment: hi @Bae can u give me way how to implemet example1 in better way?
How to get the url to be played?

Comment: hi @Bae, Any idea on how to get this working? I am looking for some help now.